# sqlsrv to csv using PHP

Tags: php, csv, sqlsrv

I have been work on a PHP page that will export some SQL data using sqlsrv_fetch_array to a csv file.  I am having some problems with getting the data just right in the csv file.  When I run the script the output on the csv file looks like this.

```
<html>                          
    <head>                          
        <title>Page Title</title>                           
    </head>                         
    <body>                          
"   "                           
"           "                           
        "CCCCCCC\SSSSS" 140211 B Insxxxxxx  BBB Y   N   CCCCCCC\SSSSS   Stevens_Dave    Y
CCCCCCC\SSSSS   140211 W Insxxxxxx  BBB Y   N   CCCCCCC\SSSSS   Stevens_Dave    Y
CCCCCCC\SSSSS   140411 R Intxxxxx Auxxx BBB Y   N   CCCCCCC\SSSSS   Stevens_Dave    Y
```

Notice that the first "CCCCCC\SSSS" still has the " around it even though the rest of the information does not.  Also for some reason it is posting the HTML stuff at the top of the csv file.  I would like it to put the headers there but can't seem to figure out how to get it working.  Can you take a look at the code and let me know where the problem is along with how to add the headers to the csv file as well?  Here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <?php 

$userid = $_POST['userid']; //defined through a form


        $serverName = "server1, 1433";
$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>"adminweb", "PWD"=>"adminweb", "Database"=>"dbname");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Could not connect.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Set up and execute the query. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile u INNER JOIN UserTeam ut ON u.UserID = ut.UserOrTeam WHERE UserID LIKE '%xxxx%'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )  {
 foreach($row AS $key => $value){
        //If the character " exists, then escape it, otherwise the csv file will be invalid.
        $pos = strpos($value, '"');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
        }
        $out .= '"'.$value.'",';
    }
    $out .= "\n";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($results);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
// Output to browser with the CSV mime type
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testcsv.csv");
echo $out;



 ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing...

```
<html>                          
    <head>                          
        <title>Page Title</title>                           
    </head>                         
    <body>
```

from the top of your PHP script.